# electronで外部のmoduleを使う方法

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js, electron

electronでcasper.jsを使おうと考えています。
main.jsにて

```
require ('casper');
```

と書いて実行すると

> Cannot find module 'casper'

と表示されてしまいます。
electronでは外部のmoduleは使えないのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは、回答がなかったようなので。

まずCasperJSはjsのモジュールではありません。
あとElectronはnode.jsで動いているため、node.jsから外部コマンドを実行するようにしてあげなければなりません。しかしnpmをみてみるとphantom.jsはnode-phantomと言ったようなモジュールがあります。

そこで今回ご質問のcasperJSは調べたところ、SpookyJSというのがあるみたいです。
https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS

こちらでいけると思います。

もし外部から読み込む方式なら、child_processを呼び出して、exec関数を作ってあげるとよいと思われます。